# "May not respond to" warning

Tags: objective-c, ios4

A very specific question, so doing research on it is kind of hard. It seems pretty straightforward to me, but I'm doing something wrong and I can't see what it is.

I've created the following method:

```
- (NSComparisonResult) searchBuildingObject:(NSDictionary *) building forString:(NSString *) searchString {

    NSComparisonResult buildingComparison = [[building objectForKey:@"building"] compare:searchString
                                                                                 options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)
                                                                                   range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchString length])];

    if (buildingComparison != NSOrderedSame) {

        for (NSString *alias in [building objectForKey:@"alias"]) {

            NSComparisonResult aliasComparison = [alias compare:searchString
                                                        options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)
                                                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchString length])];

            if (aliasComparison == NSOrderedSame)
                return aliasComparison;
        }
    }

    return buildingComparison;

}
```

It seems to be working fine, even when I test the method it gives me the correct results. Yet, I still get a warning upon calling the method:

```
[self searchBuildingObject:[self.buildings objectForKey:building] forString:searchText]
```

I made sure building is an NSDictionary, and searchString is definitely an NSString. The result of the method is an NSComparisonResult which I then compare to NSOrderedSame

```
NSComparisonResult result = [self searchBuildingObject:[self.buildings objectForKey:building] forString:searchText];
if (result == NSOrderedSame) NSLog(@"Same");
```

The warning I'm getting is "BuildingsViewController may not respond to '-searchBuildingObject:forString:'. Does anybody see what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That warning usually indicates that you have forgotten to declare the method in the interface of the referred-to object:

```
@interface BuildingsViewController : ControllerSuperclass {
       // Declaration of ivars...
}

- (NSComparisonResult) searchBuildingObject:(NSDictionary *) building forString:(NSString *) searchString;
// Other method declarations...

@end
```

The reason it's a warning and not an error is that it's the compiler complaining that it's not *certain* that you can call that method on that object. The `@interface` declaration is what the compiler looks at to make that determination.

The compiler also knows about methods which were not declared, but which are defined *before* you call them (this only applies within a single compilation unit -- loosely speaking, a class can call its own method which doesn't have a declaration, without the compiler complaining, *if* the method's implementation is located previous to its use in the file; not a great thing to rely on).

The method lookup/resolution is done later, at runtime, and the compiler doesn't know about that. Because the method does actually exist on your class, the call succeeds at that time.

Comment: Ahh, I see now! Thanks. One thing I don't get though, is why I've never gotten this error before. I created methods before that I didn't declare (I forgot, and I didn't get an error reminding me), but this is the first time I get this error...

Comment: Possibly they were methods from the superclass which you just overrode?

Comment: Not likely, but I guess possible, I don't remember the exact situations anymore. Does it make a difference whether I pass arguments or not? This was my first method that required arguments, so maybe that could be it?

Comment: Whether the method has parameters makes no difference. I don't know why that happened, but the compiler must have seen a declaration for them somewhere. If you're implementing protocols or overriding in a subclass, that counts as declaration.

Comment: "I created methods before that I didn't declare, but this is the first time I get this error..." Maybe you implemented those methods **above** any calls to them...

Comment: @albertamg: I usually do that yes. Is that why the compiler isn't complaining then, because it's seen that method is defined when that code is executed?

Comment: "Is that why the compiler isn't complaining then, because it's seen that method is defined when that code is executed?" - Yes, that's how it works in C and it's variants.

Answer (score 3):

In some cases, it can't be defined in classes in that case you can use the following:

```
[obj performSelector:@selector(methodName)];
```

Not preferred but when you need it, you need it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that this method is declared in your `@interface`!!